# How to append a Modin pandas dataframe to other?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandasql, modin

I am working on performing calculations on large files around **6GB** each file and came across **Modin pandas** which I heard optimized compared to pandas.

I need to read a CSV file in chunks and perform calculations on that and append it to a big **dataframe** and convert the big dataframe to a **CSV** file again.

This is working absolutely fine with **Pandas**. But it's taking too much time to process even small files. And I can't even imagine it for **6GB** files.

However, when I try to do the same thing with modin pandas, it is unable to append dataframe to a big dataframe which I want to convert to csv file.

Can anyone suggest any alternative to this or a solution.

```
Python - 3.6
Pandas - 0.24.2
Modin Pandas - 0.5.2
```

**Code.**

```
import modin.pandas as pd

def calculate_visit_prioritization(df):
    # calculations here
    return df

def get_all_data():
    big_df = pd.DataFrame()
    for df in pd.read_csv('./samp.csv', chunksize=50):
        big_df = big_df.append(calculate_visit_prioritization(df))
    big_df.to_csv('samps3.csv', index=False)

def main():
    get_all_data()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Error when using Modin pandas to append dataframes.**

> UserWarning: `DataFrame.append` for empty DataFrame defaulting to
>   pandas implementation.
>
> File
>   "/home/tony/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/reshape/concat.py",
>   line 289, in `__init__` raise TypeError(msg)
>
> TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type ""; only pd.Series, pd.DataFrame,
>   and pd.Panel (deprecated) objs are valid

I have gone through this [link](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/UsingPandasonRay/dataframe_supported.html?highlight=append) where it's said the pandas's `.append()` function is **partially ( P )** implemented in Modin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modin's USP is that the only difference between pandas and modin pandas is the import statement. To concatenate multiple DataFrames, use a single `pd.concat` call rather than N `append` calls for better performance.

```
df_list = []
for df in pd.read_csv('./samp.csv', chunksize=50):
    df_list.append(calculate_visit_prioritization(df))

big_df = pd.concat(df_list, ignore_index=True)
big_df.to_csv('samps3.csv', index=False)
```

This should gracefully handle empty sub-DataFrames as well.